# Return JavaScript Promise rejected fulfilled value

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, google-geocoder

I'm trying to use node-geocoder npm package to get latitude and longitude of position some objects.

Could you help me please to understand JavaScript promises.

Here is an example code:

```js
import nodeGeocoder from 'node-geocoder'

function getLocation (str) {
    // Selecting Google as provider
    const geocoder = nodeGeocoder({
        provider: 'google',
    })

    return geocoder.geocode(str)
        .then(response => {
            // I want to return latitude an longitude
            return [response[0].latitude, response[0].longitude]
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(`Geocoder Error: ${ error }`)
        })
}

export default getLocation
```

So. This is a test (Jest framework):

```js
import getLocation from './index'

test('Checking', () => {
    expect(getLocation('29 champs elysée paris')).toEqual([48.8698679, 2.3072976])
})
```

When I'm trying to use this test I just get promise status `{"fulfillmentValue": undefined, "isFulfilled": false, "isRejected": false, "rejectionReason": undefined}`.

But I need to get just promise resolved result. How can I do it?

I don't want to edit test

Comment: You cannot return the result that has not yet arrived yet. Wait for the promise that you got to fulfill.

Answer (score 1):

For testing, most test suites offer an async callback for all your promise based tests. I would expect it (pun intended) to work like this:

```
import getLocation from './index'

test('Checking', (done) => {
  getLocation('29 champs elysée paris').then(geoData => {
    expect(geoData).toEqual([48.8698679, 2.3072976]);
    done();
  }).catch(error => {
    done(error)
  });
});
```

Depending on the testing framework you might be using, the way you call the resolver callback (i.e: `done()`) can change. However, the pattern should more or less be the same.

Comment: But I don't want to update test. And if I change a value from array in your test - test also will be successfully passed